# subscribe to a topic without specifying type

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is is possible to subscribe to a specific topic, without specifying the message type?

I need to pass the message to a Lua interpreter, and I want to avoid having one C++ function for each type I want to subscribe (which would be every message in actionlib_msgs, control_msgs, diagnostic_msgs, geometry_msgs, map_msgs, nav_msgs, pcl_msgs, sensor_msgs, shape_msgs, std_msgs, tf2_geometry_msgs, tf2_msgs, tf2_sensor_msgs, trajectory_msgs, visualization_msgs)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228280/subscribe-to-a-topic-without-specifying-type/) by [federico.ferri](https://answers.ros.org/users/3836/federico.ferri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-03-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-06**:
Have you seen [wiki/roslua](http://wiki.ros.org/roslua)? It's a bit old (although the [lua-5.2](https://github.com/timn/roslua/tree/lua-5.2) branch is pretty recent), but it could provide you with some idea of how to tackle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [topic_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools) package provides a [ShapeShifter](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/topic_tools/html/classtopic__tools_1_1ShapeShifter.html) class which can be used to subscribe to any topic, but the API is still limited to either passing around serialized messages, or message types that are known at compile time.

The relay node from topic_tools provides a simple example of how to publish and subscribe generically: [relay.cpp](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/tools/topic_tools/src/relay.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0